# Find total revenue generated from "Male" customers in "Electronics" category? But output should display total revenue by prod_subcat

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have joined 3 tables for getting total revenue of each sub categories under electronics category.

But in output instead of getting specific revenue for each sub category I am getting one common value(total revenue generated by electronics category) for each sub category.

```
select prod_subcat as subcat, sum(total_amt) as total_revenue
from transection
left join customer_details
  on transection.cust_id = customer_details.customer_ID
left join [dbo].[Product_cat_info]
  on [dbo].[transection].[prod_cat_code] = [dbo].[Product_cat_info].[Prod_Cat_cod]
where Gender like 'M' and prod_Cat in (
  select prod_Cat
  from [dbo].[Product_cat_info] 
  where prod_Cat like 'Electronics'
)
group by [prod_subcat]
```

The output which I am getting is

```
     subcat               total_revenue

  Personal Appliances       5702069
  Mobiles                   5702069
  Computers                 5702069
  Audio and video           5702069
  Cameras                   5702069
```

Comment: If it isn't too late I would suggest changing the name of your table. There is no letter 'e' in transaction. Also, why use like 'M'? How about = 'M' instead. Like is used for wildcard searches. When you know the value you want you should use =. To really help here we need some details. [mcve]

Comment: `prod_Cat like 'Electronics'` should be `prod_Cat = 'Electronics'`

Comment: like is an expensive operation; if you are sure that prod_Cat  =  'Electronics'  do so.Same for Gender. Will help you get your desired result set faster.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this subquery in IN causing more duplicates as you have already joined this table and replace this below query first also, add prod_cat to group by

```
 prod_Cat in (select prod_Cat from [dbo]. 
  [Product_cat_info] 
  where prod_Cat like 'Electronics')
```

with `and prod_Cat like 'Electronics'`

Comment: Hii sir, I tried what you suggested me but the output is still same.

Comment: I get it you forgot to add prod_category in group by

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT prod_subcat as subcat,
    gender, 
    sum(total_amt) as total_revenue
    from tbl_Tran T1
    left join tbl_Cust C1
      on T1.cust_id = C1.customer_ID
    left join Prod_cat_info P1
      on T1.prod_cat_code = P1.prod_cat_code
      and T1.prod_subcat_code=P1.prod_sub_cat_code
    where Gender like 'M' and prod_Cat in (
      select prod_Cat
      from Prod_cat_info 
      where prod_Cat like 'Electronics'
    )
    group by prod_subcat,Gender
```

Replace tbl_tran with transaction
and tbl_cust with customer

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(TOTAL_AMT) AS TOTAL_AMT , prod_subcat  FROM DBO.prod_INFO   AS A
LEFT JOIN DBO.Transactions AS B ON A.prod_cat_code =B.prod_cat_coDE AND A.prod_sub_cat_code 
=B.prod_subcat_codE
LEFT JOIN DBO.Customer AS C ON B.cust_id = C.customer_Id 
WHERE PROD_CAT IN ('ELECTRONICS') AND GENDER = 'M'
GROUP BY
prod_subcat
```

There is no need for inline subquery in `WHERE` statement.